# Gradle: Overriding Dependency with Different Name

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I am trying to import [`org.scalatra:scalatra-atmosphere:2.2.0-RC3`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatra/scalatra-atmosphere/2.2.0-RC3) into a Scala 2.10 project. The issue is that this package depends on the two non-Scala-versioned packages `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor:2.0.4` and `com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit:2.0.4` (`org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.2` and `org.scalatra:scalatra-json:2.2.0-RC3` should work fine, as they will go to newest). As far as I can tell, the Akka dependencies do not exist on Maven Central, so we have broken packages.

I would like to override `org.scalatra:scalatra-atmosphere:2.2.0-RC3`'s dependencies by hand by replacing the non-Scala-versioned packages with Scala-versioned packages that actually exist:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.typesafe.akka') {
                details.requested.name += "_$scalaVersion"
                details.useVersion '2.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this technique appears to be explicitly disallowed as of Gradle 1.4:

```
 What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> new ModuleRevisionId MUST have the same ModuleId as original one. original = com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor new = com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10
```

Is there a legitimate way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only version changes are supported in 1.4, 1.5 is due to contain support for changing the other attributes of a dependency.

I think your options are variations on excluding the specific dependency and adding it back in by hand. Examples can be found in [the docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#exclude-dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.scalatra:scalatra-atmosphere:2.2.0-RC3) {
        exclude group: 'com.typesafe.akka', module: 'akka-actor'
        exclude group: 'com.typesafe.akka', module: 'akka-testkit'
    }
    // assuming you have this available in a repository your build is configured to resolve against
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor:2.0.4-MY.LOCAL.VERSION' 
}
```